# Why I can't see New project Web Template for Visual Studio 2015 preview?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 preview successfully. Unfortunately, I am not getting New project Templates to create Web Apps (asp.net). I am looking under C# -> Web.

Please note that I tried this locally and on an Azure machine which is having Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found the solution of the issue, stated above. I am sharing here, so that others can get benefited, who might be wondering for the solution of similar issues.

I resolved it after re-installing/Update the setup. Here are the step(s):

-Restart the setup for VS2015 Preview
-Selected the required components to install

[image]

After these steps, I received the desired templates.

P.S. Whenever anyone is installing VS2015 Preview first time, should Select the features under '**Optional features to install**' to get the desired installation.

Comment: I have followed the same procedre but still after reinstalling many times, there is no option for web project in new project

Comment: @Rachit Gupta: I had the same issue and managed to finally get it resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37835629/842238

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with the Web templates not showing up in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.  I uninstalled and reinstalled "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" from the update menu, tried repair, installed various related templates, and it wouldn't come back.

I know it's normally in the Visual Studio 2015 installer, but for me I finally got it back by clicking and installing whatever the ASP.Net 4.6 "Install For Windows" link does at https://get.asp.net/.  No idea why, hope it helps someone.

Comment: Have you installed ASP.NET Core RC1 if yes, first uninstall all RC and then try to install. Also, try to use offline installers

Comment: Sorry, that link now appears to be dead.  It redirects to https://www.microsoft.com/net, and I can't find the original download.  In case it comes back you used to get to it by clicking "Get ASP.NET" from here: http://www.asp.net/.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. I first installed the VS2015 community edition and then uninstalled it and installed the VS2015 Professional edition. Professional edition didn't had any Web Templates.

Issue was resolved by installing [DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows).

I faced some issue while installing the DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2, which was resolved by following the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134048/problems-installing-dot-net-core-1-0-0-vs-2015-tools-preview-2/38499007).