# VS 2015 Preview missing "ASP.NET 5 Web Application" project type?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

In Visual Studio 2015 Preview, I see the following vNext templates in the "New Project" window:

[image: vNext Project templates in Visual Studio 2015]

I am under the impression that I should also see an entry for "ASP.NET 5 Empty Web Application" or something similar, but I see no such thing. Those two entries are the only "vNext" designated entries that I have installed.

Is there an additional binary I need to install in order to enable this type of project to appear? Or do I need to examine my VS 2015 Preview installation?

Note: I do have an entry for "ASP.NET Web Application", which takes me through the setup with the unified architecture but does not appear to include a `project.json` file or things that I'm associating with ASP.NET 5 development.

**Update:** Per [this article regarding 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0fyc0azh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I also tried to run `devenv.exe /installvstemplates`, but that didn't work either. To clarify, I don't see any new web template, which the screenshot below illustrates as well:

[image]

Comment: I am attempting to repair my VS 2015 installation now to see if that remedies the situation.

Comment: After a repair of VS 2015, I still do not see any options for "ASP.NET 5 Web Application" or similar.

Comment: Selecting a different target .NET Framework version changes the templates listed. Just one thing to try if you can't find the right template.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 Preview contains everything you need to create an ASP.NET 5 (vNext) web application. One additional generic option should be available that's not depicted in your question:

[image: Web template options]

It's not entirely clear at this point, but choosing the generic web application option will present a few ASP.NET 5 (vNext) options that you're seeking in the following dialog:

[image: ASP.NET Web Application templates]

Comment: That was 100% the issue. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 31):

I was having the same problem, except that unlike the accepted answer suggests, the ASP.NET Web Application was not on the list of templates at all.

I was able to get it to show up after following the instructions from  [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/08/some-of-asp-net-project-templates-in-vs-2015-are-available-on-vs-gallery.aspx).

1. From Visual Studio 2015: `Tools -> Extensions and Updates`
2. Select `Online` then click `Visual Studio Gallery`
3. Search for `ASP.NET Project Templates` and download the first result.
4. Go through installation process, relaunch Visual Studio, and Web Application should now be an option!

Alternately, you can download the templates directly [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9402d38e-2a85-434e-8d6a-8fc075068a42).

I believe this download actually is meant to install some other templates that I wasn't interested in, but installing them must have also installed the base template in the process. Either way, it worked for me.

Comment: For anyone else searching , this added the missing "ASP .Net Core Web Application (.NET Core) Visual C#" that was missing from my copy of VS 2015 Professional even after doing update 3.

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio 2015 Preview Microsoft has renamed `ASP.NET vNext` to `ASP.NET 5`

If you open http://www.asp.net/vnext, in every article `vNext` is metioned as `ASP.NET 5`

Comment: Awesome! That might very well be it. And in that case, it wouldn't carry the blue "vNext" overlay still, correct? Because I'd looked for that previously. Repairing VS now but once that's done I'll check to confirm.

Comment: Also, I'm aware of all of the references to ASP.NET 5, but I don't recall seeing an ASP.NET 5 project in the list, only "ASP.NET Web Application" which seemed to be the old style. I'll check and confirm.

Comment: So it turns out I'm not sure this is the answer. While I agree that  you're correct about asp.net 5 vs vNext, I still don't see an "ASP.NET 5 web application" option in VS 2015; only "ASP.NET Web Application" which does not use `project.json`, etc. I'll update the question to reflect the terminology though. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In following Sam's Suggestion, I noticed that there were Updates Pending. One of these updates included the missing ASP.NET 5 templates.

Tools > Extensions & Updates > Updates > Visual Studio Gallery

Once updated & Installed, the Web Application was then available as described in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The new update released this week has renamed ASP.NET 5 into a new framework which they are now calling ASP.NET Core. More information can be found in this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/

Comment: Thanks for posting up. No wonder I wasn't able to find the ASP.NET 5 templates! I spent a good hour or more trying different updates & restarting, and the ****ing thing was there the whole time!

Answer (score 1):

VS 2015 Preview is going under *ASP.net Core web application.* If you cant see that one under templates you may go to [this](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) site and download **.NET Core 1.0 for Visual Studio** then install.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ### In my case the problem was in the **Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2** corrupted installation.
>
> #### It was performed:
>
> - install the **ASP.NET Project Templates** following answer from this post - *NO RESULT*
> - reinstalling **Microsoft Web Developer Tools** from the identical SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451754/why-i-cant-see-new-project-web-template-for-visual-studio-2015-preview) - *NO RESULT*
> - fresh install the IDE using [TotalUninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases) tool - *NO RESULT*
> - repair the **[Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015)** (see the sketch below) - ***SOLVED***
>
> #### Only repair [.NET Core 1.0.1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015) finally solved the problem!
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to download the `.net core cross platform development`, below steps you will refer

1. open **VISUAL Studio installer**
2. click the option in the list click modify
3. below image you can refer it
   [image]
4. once complete installation,now you have the option for `asp.net core web application`