# There is only ' empty asp.net project '

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I can't create a project using web form or mvc template. I can only make an empty [project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Lha.png)

Comment: Try manual install http://stackoverflow.com/a/29403530/5922158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At bottom of central part you can see a link 'click here to go online....'. Click it, find a necessary template and install it

Comment: i can't find it there