# The 'ConnectedServicesPackage' package did not load correctly visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I keep getting this error message everytime I open or create a new project:

[image: ConnectedServicesPackage]

Anyone else getting this error and fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem and the only way I was able to get past it was to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 using **vs_enterprise.exe /uninstall /force** (depending on what version you have exe could be named differently)

Then I physically deleted the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0** directory

Then I reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 again and it worked

Comment: Took me some time to test this out. I've done what you said, but now I'm missing web templates, even after repair. Just to make it clear what I'm missing, see the first screenshot on this site http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html has the web in the treeview.

Comment: It seems that the accepted answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451754/why-i-cant-see-new-project-web-template-for-visual-studio-2015-preview has the fix. Microsoft Web Developer Tools wasn't installed...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this problem is in institute a Repair of Visual Studio from Add/Remove programs. I ran into this rather frustrating problem and funnily enough, uninstall / reinstall did not fix this, but 'Repair' did!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted \ renamed my profile appdata vs directory and solve the problem:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
```

After that, the problem with other packages comes. I try many options (delete folders, uninstall, repair, ...) None of them worked. And when i was thinking in format the OS. I **remove the user folder** and solve all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

this has been said in the comments, but because it is very important and it solved this problem completely I am putting it as an answer.

> It seems that the accepted answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/27469861/4390133

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it just repairing Visual Studio. I went to Visual Studio Installer and ran repair. [image]