# Web Projects in VS2015 Update 1 Professional are Missing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

On one machine, I don't have the Web Projects.

First of all I had a Ultimate Trial, there I had the webprojects. Then I uninstalled it and installed the Professional, since then all web projects (4.5 and 5 rc) are missing.

I did [install the Web Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451754/why-i-cant-see-new-project-web-template-for-visual-studio-2015-preview). I Also [installed and repaired the asp 5](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html).

I also uninstalled VS2015 and reinstalled it.

On all other machines even those where i also uninstalled the ultimate it works fine I don't want to reinstall the whole machine :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset to default templates back by using the following command line (run as local Admin):

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

**UPDATE**: also removing folders **ItemTemplatesCache** and **ProjectTemplatesCache** from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE might help. It is pretty safe to delete them but I would backup just for any cases.

Comment: did not help. also resetting user settings did not help. finally i reinstalled the whole operating system, now it works...