# Problems installing Dot Net Core 1.0.0 VS 2015 Tools Preview 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

Each time I try to install the **DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe** package I get an error saying the following:

> Setup Failed One or more issues caused the setup to fail.  Please fix
>   the issues and then retry setup.  For more information see the log
>   file. Setup has detected that Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 may not be
>   completely installed.  Please repair Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, then
>   install this product again.

When I look into the log file, I find the following line which seems to be causing the error during install:

> Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR NOT(((VS2015CommunityUpdateVersion <>
>   VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015CommunityExists) AND
>   (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015ProfessionalUpdateVersion <>
>   VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015ProfessionalExists) AND
>   (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015EnterpriseUpdateVersion <>
>   VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015EnterpriseExists) AND
>   (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015WebExpressUpdateVersion <>
>   VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015WebExpressExists) AND
>   (VS2015UpdateVersionExists))) OR (SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1) OR
>   (WixBundleAction=2)' evaluates to false.

A simple repair of Update 3 has not resolved the issue, so I was attempting to resort to an uninstall/reinstall of the update.  When going through

> Control Panel > Programs and Features > View Installed updates

to uninstall the update, it jumps right to the "`Setup Completed`" screen saying that all of the components have been uninstalled without any progress screen.  Then when I attempt to run the Update 3 installer it says the Update is already installed.

I then tried using Revo Uninstaller but the same thing happens after cleaning out folders and registry items.

I even tried doing an `/uninstall /force` on the package but to no avail.  It seems something is remaining stuck somewhere that keeps the update registered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm facing the similar too

Comment: Same here. Did anyone find a stable solution to this issue?

Comment: No, no solution.  We decided to move our development process off of our local PC's anyway and instead ran a clean install on a VM.  All other attempts I have made on my local PC have resulted in numerous errors.  I cannot even install VS 2015 without errors occurring at this point.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I was able to install it by running with SKIP_VSU_CHECK parameter

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```

Comment: I will give it a shot sir. By the way, how did you know this SKIP_VSU_CHECK is a command line parameter rather that some other kind of entity?

Comment: This worked. It is concerning because the error message said: "setup has detected that visual studio 2015 update 3 may not be fully installed...". Makes me wonder if other problems will pop up down the road.

Comment: source is: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling#release-notes-and-known-issues

Comment: This works, I should've seen this before I tried repairing my installation twice in the PC. It was a successful installation without these in my laptop, I don't know how that worked

Comment: I tried installing preview 2 both on my office and then home pc before searching for this issue. Thanks for the lead Andrey! God bless you with long life.

Answer (score 22):

**EDIT: I believe that [Andrey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38499007/73801) is probably better long term, as it doesn't involve registry hacking.  Please try his instructions below first.**  I will leave my original answer in place for posterity.

---

I received the same error message on a fresh Windows 10 install, with a fresh Visual Studio 2015 install.  I believe the VS2015 install process automatically downloaded and applied Update 3 during the process.

Chasing the logfile showed that it was comparing several version numbers.  In my case, the 'Community' edition version mismatched.

```
[27B8:1BBC][2016-07-20T16:17:11]i000: Setting string variable 'VS2015UpdateVersion' to value '14.0.25420'
[27B8:1BBC][2016-07-20T16:17:11]i000: Setting string variable 'VS2015ProfessionalUpdateVersion' to value '14.0.25420'
[1A60:0CD4][2016-07-20T16:14:36]i000: Setting string variable 'VS2015CommunityUpdateVersion' to value    '14.0.25424'
```

Nobody in the history of the internet has ever used version `14.0.25424`, so I assumed it must be a typo.  After changing the VS Community `UpdateVersion` string value from `14.0.25424` to `14.0.25420` in the registry, the installer worked fine for me.

The full registry keys to check include:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\community
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\community\1033
```

Both should have the following string value:

```
"UpdateVersion"="14.0.25420"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that in my case, there was another version key hidden in \community (so there are 2 "UpdateVersion" you need to check). \community and \community\1033

Comment: Thanks!  This answer worked for me, but I had to also change:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise`

Comment: You saved my life Matt... I was frustrated.. Thank you so much.. I wonder how did you figure this out...

Comment: Matt I initially marked your's as the answer because I felt it was a bit more permanent, but based on your suggestion and popularity I have marked Andrey's answer as the answer to my question.  I have used both to solve this problem since asking.

Comment: @Xipooo - Not a prob.  I'm just glad its fixed. =)

Answer (score 5):

Know issues, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3-rc, details a similar issue with preview1.

May be worth keeping an eye on for updates about preview2.

I have the same issue but haven't solved it yet. My version numbers are different to those listed for the fix for preview 1, this answer is just pointing you to the official issue page.

[Update] the official word on this is at https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling is

"Due to a known issue in the setup detection logic, even though you have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 RC installed, you might see the following message when you run the installer. This will be fixed in the next build. For now, to work around this and bypass the check, you can run the EXE from a command prompt and then pass SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1 at the end. "

[Update 2] - for **in-depth info on upgrading *to* rc2 *from* rc1**, David Pine's blog on the steps required is very good.

ievangelist dot github dot io /blog/migrating-to-rc2/

Answer (score 2):

I tried this first from @Andrey

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```

This partly worked as in I was able to complete the installations. On VS startup there was a warning message that some components would not work. I was able to edit code but not to run an example app.

I remembered an earlier warning message from the "Visual Studio Community 2015" installation about mismatching versions of "Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable". So my next experiment was to go into "Control Panel -- Programs and Features" and uninstall the 2 x examples I found "(x64)" and "(x86)". I then ran a repair installation of "Visual Studio Community 2015". Success.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the installed from cmd using the following:
**DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1**

Installed without any issues

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but none of the above answers helped me.

The issue can be caused by the exe trying to download content via IE so it might not be enough to simply change a setting or two from IE but it's recommended to reset them to default, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using CMD and run this command

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe /layout
```