# Fatal error when installing Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 VS 2015 Tooling preview 2

Tags: asp.net, .net, installation, asp.net-core, windows-7-x64

I try to install the DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.1 package

I am having the following error message : 
0x80070643 Fatal error during installation

Here is the part of the log where it seems to fail :

> [236C:2014][2016-08-24T10:37:57]i338: Acquiring package:
>   DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, download
>   from:
>   https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/8/2F864C4E-6980-4AFC-B64E-0AC04837FD6C/packages/DotNetVersionManager-x64_rc2_39.msi
>   [26B0:27A8][2016-08-24T10:37:58]i305: Verified acquired payload:
>   DotNetVersionManager_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache.unverified\DotNetVersionManager_x64, moving to:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{4EC36977-42B9-3C18-A692-B9DEE7404484}v1.0.11123.0\packages\DotNetVersionManager-x64_rc2_39.msi.
>   [236C:2014][2016-08-24T10:37:58]w343: Prompt for source of package:
>   AspNetCoreLocalFeed, payload: AspNetCoreLocalFeed, path:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\packages\AspNetCoreLocalFeed_rc2_39.msi
>   [236C:2014][2016-08-24T10:37:58]i338: Acquiring package:
>   AspNetCoreLocalFeed, payload: AspNetCoreLocalFeed, download from:
>   https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/8/2F864C4E-6980-4AFC-B64E-0AC04837FD6C/packages/AspNetCoreLocalFeed_rc2_39.msi
>   [26B0:26B4][2016-08-24T10:37:58]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to
>   install MSI package. [26B0:26B4][2016-08-24T10:37:58]e000: Error
>   0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
>   [236C:0874][2016-08-24T10:37:58]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to
>   configure per-machine MSI package.

I tried to repair VS 2015 Update 3, but i still can't install the Tooling preview 2.0.1.

I then tried the [SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1 method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134048/problems-installing-dot-net-core-1-0-0-vs-2015-tools-preview-2) does not work.

I tried to disable the firewall and it doesn't work.

I have VS 2015 Entreprise working on my machine (Windows 7 x64)
I already installed the .NET Core 1.0.0 SDK successfully

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution alone : 
I switched the language of VS 2015 from french to english (Installing a [package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48157)) Then the Tooling preview installation worked properly !

I hope it might help