# DotNetCore 1.0.0 VS2015 Tools Preview2 installation fail

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I create an offline installation of `DotNetCore.1.0.0 VS2015 Tools Preview2` with `/layout` option successfully. But when I try install it I got this error:

> One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and them retry setup. For more information see the log file.
>
> 0x80070001 - Incorrect function

When I inspect the detailed log file, I found the reason of error:

> Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'D:\Install\DotnetCore-Offline\'
>
> Error 0x80070001: Failed to extract all files from container, erf: 1:2:0
>
> Error 0x80070001: Failed to wait for operation complete.
>
> Error 0x80070001: Failed to open container.
>   Error 0x80070001: Failed to open container: WixAttachedContainer.

I became of read [Problems installing Dot Net Core 1.0.0 VS 2015 Tools Preview 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134048/problems-installing-dot-net-core-1-0-0-vs-2015-tools-preview-2), but is not the same problem. The detailed complete log file can be downloaded [here](https://gist.github.com/josephrodriguez/1d57769ba896866791170aa78efbf860).

**Question:**

- How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have Update 3 installed for your VS? You probably may want to have a look [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015) and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current).

Comment: Yes, I have installed Update 3 of Visual Studio, let me check this links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this problem happened only to me and I will be the only person because it is fixed with **DotNetCore 1.0.1 VS2015 Tools Preview 2.0.3** [downloaded](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current) in the link provided by @Kos.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem! The *DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe* file on my machine was different to the *DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe* file on Microsoft's download site (586KB vs 680KB). I can only assume that they messed up their versioning at some point and that the buggy installer has the same version number as the correct one!