# Web projects missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I recently did a complete uninstall and reinstall of my Visual Studio 2015 Community installation as it was behaving rather odd.  However, after reinstall I no longer have any Web templates in the New Project window.  I have tried several methods, all of which have not worked:

- Repaired the Visual Studio installation
- Uninstall and reinstall the ASP.NET Web Framework and Tools extension
- Uninstall and reinstall the .NET Core tooling
- Run devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates

Visual Studio can still open and run web solutions (ASP.NET MVC 4) and, to some extent, ASP.NET Core projects (IIS Express does not work).  The .NET Core project list does not list Web Application either.

This is extremely frustrating: does anyone have any thoughts on how to resolve this other than run another complete uninstall (with VSUninstaller tool on GitHub) or even resetting my Windows 10 installation?

Comment: Did you follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451754/why-i-cant-see-new-project-web-template-for-visual-studio-2015-preview it (also see comments on it) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015/37835629#37835629

Comment: Yes - unfortunately, they are still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue in the end although I am not entirely sure how!  After more uninstallations, reinstallations and updates the web projects became available again.

However, if anyone has any thoughts on a more robust solution please let me know.

Answer (score -3):

Sometime setup has been crashed so it could be like this form of crashed so check your setup.
if setup in good condition then u have install online tools for Web or search them in NuGetPackege.

Comment: The installation appears to be fine - everything else is working as expected (UWP, etc.) - I have tried installing the ASP.NET tools several times which does not work.  They are not included in a NuGet package.